# UWP MediaPlayerElement - Poster Stay Put Until Played

Tags: video, uwp, media, poster

The UWP MediaPlayerElement has both a PosterSource and a VideoSource.  This question is primarily about keeping the PosterSource showing until Play.

[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaplayerelement.postersource?view=winrt-19041#remarks) state:

- When a valid source is not set. For example, Source is not set,
  Source was set to Null, or the source is invalid (as is the case when
  a MediaFailed event fires).
- While media is loading. For example, a
  valid source is set, but the MediaOpened event has not fired yet.
- When media is streaming to another device.
- When the media is audio only.

What I'm trying to determine is how to keep the Poster image showing even after the Media has finished downloading when auto play is off.  Sadly the first frame+ is a black screen.  So I want the poster to show until the play button is pressed.

Ideas?

**EDIT:**

Faywang was very helpful.

In addition to his comments I did the following:

```
private void PlayPauseButton_EnabledChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = (sender as AppBarButton);
    if(!(bool)e.newValue)
    {
        button.IsEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Based on the document, it mentions "while media is loading. For example, a valid source is set, but the MediaOpened event has not fired yet.". Before you click the play button, the media has beed loaded, so the poster will disappear. If you want to keep the poster until you click the play button, maybe you could set the PosterSource and don't set the Source to MediaPlayerElement at first. Then listen the click event of play button, when the event is triggered, you could set the Source in this event and play it.

Comment: @Faywang.  The MediaPlayerElement (MPE) does not let me adjust the Play button.  Without a source it is disabled. There is no TransportControl option for IsPlayEnabled like there is for the MediaPlayer.SystemMediaMTransportControls.  I tried to set it to true, but it does not affect the MPE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep the poster until you click the play button, you could set the PosterSource and don't set the Source to MediaPlayerElement at first. Then listen the click event of play button, when the event is triggered, you could set the Source in this event and play it.

In addition, by testing, when you explicitly set AutoPlay and also do not set the Source, the play button will be disable. But if you do not set the AutoPlay, the play button will be enable, so it's better to **remove** this code `AutoPlay="False"`.

If you want to listen the click event of play button, you could get the default style of MediaTransportControls and subscribe the click event of the play button. You can go to **generic.xaml** file to get the default style of MediaTransportControls. In the default style, there is an **AppBarButton** named **PlayPauseButton** which represents play and pause button, so you can add click event in it and when trigger the event, set the source, play/pauce the video.

For example:

.xaml:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="MediaTransportControls" x:Key="MyStyle">
        ......
        <Setter Property="Template">
            ......
            <AppBarButton x:Name='PlayPauseButton' Style='{StaticResource  AppBarButtonStyle}' 
                          Click="PlayPauseButton_Click"
                          MediaTransportControlsHelper.DropoutOrder='23'>
                <AppBarButton.Icon>
                    <SymbolIcon x:Name="PlayPauseSymbol" Symbol="Play" />
                </AppBarButton.Icon>
            </AppBarButton>
            ......
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<MediaPlayerElement x:Name="mediaSimple" Width="400" PosterSource="Assets/3.jpg" AreTransportControlsEnabled="True">
    <MediaPlayerElement.TransportControls>
        <MediaTransportControls Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}"></MediaTransportControls>
    </MediaPlayerElement.TransportControls>
</MediaPlayerElement>
```

.cs:

```
private void PlayPauseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SymbolIcon symbol = (sender as AppBarButton).Icon as SymbolIcon;
    if (symbol.Symbol == Symbol.Pause)
    {
        mediaSimple.MediaPlayer.Pause();
    }
    else
    {
        if (mediaSimple.Source == null)
        {
            mediaSimple.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/fishes.wmv"));
        }

        mediaSimple.MediaPlayer.Play();
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't setting the source later, after Play is clicked, mean a longer wait before buffering begins? I personally don't use Unity (UWP) but if this was my problem: I would put an image object on a layer above (and covering) the video while it buffers. On click of image, a "Play" command would be sent to video object, and the image would then be removed or made "not visible" (does not block any clicks to some underneath objects, also has zero opacity, etc). In other words, creating a custom poster from image object (placed on a higher layer).

Comment: @Faywang, this is great.  I'm implementing like you suggested.  The only issue is after the video completes one time.  It does go back to the poster, yet the play button is disabled.

Comment: @Faywang,  I decided to capture the PlayPauseButton_EnabledChanged event.  I noticed that something changes the state of the button so I do a quick check of the new value and if necessary re-enable it.

    private void PlayPauseButton_EnabledChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var button = (sender as AppBarButton);
        if(!(bool)e.newValue)
        {
            button.IsEnabled = true;
        }
    }